# FPDF Error, Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting

Tags: php

I tried to execute below php file to create fpdf reports.

```
<?php
require('reportspdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','I',16);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Yay TutToaster Rocks !!',0,1,'C');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

And the error comes as "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! ".

I added "xdebug.max_nesting_level=500" (I tried 200, -1 as well) line after "[xdebug]" on php.ini file, and restarted all services in WAMP server. But nothing solved the error. When trying larger number like "1000" page keep loading. Then did comment the zend extension path.

> It occured an error "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728
>   bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1792 bytes) in D:\wamp\www\Pharmacy
>   Management System\pages\reportspdf.php on line 2".

Please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: And what is the filename of the PHP file you've pasted here. Not `'reportspdf.php'` I trust?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was mistakenly put the same file name. Thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect the issue is that `'reportspdf.php'` keeps calling `require` on itself. That means it keeps trying to load itself. Try replacing line 2 with:

```
require_once('reportspdf.php');
```

And if the name of the PHP file you pasted is `reportspdf.php`, then try removing line 2 altogether.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks a lot for pointing this. I mistakenly have put same file to require.